# How to draw route between two locations in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, map-directions

How can we draw the routes between two locations in MapView using the iOS 4.0? Can some one shed light on it?

Comment: If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, YOU should invest some time in asking the question.

Comment: Thanks for the polite answer Mitch. I am sorry for not making a brief study of what I am asking? I have some other work that does not let me invest time on this. If some one has ever implemented this feature and if they explain me, I could understand it and take it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that using the MKOverlayPathView and MKPolyLine and MKPolyLineView we can draw routes in Mapview.

Answer (score 0):

Find a path finding algorithm that works for you. The A-star algorithm is probably a good one to recommend for this purpose.

Comment: I haven't used the API, but does that mean you get waypoints as well as distances between waypoints? Because otherwise there's nothing to run A-star *on* -- you'd just be connecting two dots with a straight line, which is probably not a valid route on a map.

Comment: Hi I found MKOverlayPathView in the documentation. Have you ever used it?