# how to draw route between two location in mapview

Tags: ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw route between two locations in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421051/how-to-draw-route-between-two-locations-in-iphone)

Can anyone give me a good tutorial or some examples on this?